# Why a Long Text field is returning only 255 characters in a MS ACCESS 2013 query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm doing a query, but my field (Long Text) is returning only 255 characters. I have no idea why.

My field name:

```
name: tb_Apartamentos.txt_Descricao
```

Real DB value:

```
Quarto e sala super aconchegante equipado com TV a cabo, internet wireless e ar condicionado. O destaque fica por conta da excelente localização: Rua Bolívar, entre os Postos 4 e 5. Está a poucos metros do Baixo Copacabana, encontro das ruas Domingos Ferreira, Aires Saldanha e Bolívar. É neste local que fica uma das maiores concentrações de bares de Copacabana, onde cariocas e turistas disputam um lugar nas mesas ou nas calçadas para beber e jogar conversa fora.
```

My Query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tb_Apartamentos.cod_Apartamento,
    tb_Apartamentos.txt_Titulo,
    tb_Apartamentos.txt_Descricao,
    tb_Apartamentos.txt_Endereco,
    tb_Apartamentos.txt_Bairro,
    tb_Apartamentos.txt_Cidade,
    (
        select count(tb_DisponibilidadeApartamentos.ind_Disponibilidade) 
        from tb_DisponibilidadeApartamentos 
        where ind_Disponibilidade = true 
            and tb_DisponibilidadeApartamentos.cod_Apartamento = tb_Apartamentos.cod_Apartamento  
    ) as qtd_Disponibilidade,
    (
        select count (tb_FotoApartamentos.cod_FotoApartamento) 
        from tb_FotoApartamentos 
        where tb_FotoApartamentos.cod_Apartamento = tb_Apartamentos.cod_Apartamento
    ) as qtd_FotoApartamento,
    tb_Apartamentos.txt_Periodo
FROM 
    (
        (
            tb_Apartamentos
            LEFT JOIN 
            tb_DisponibilidadeApartamentos 
                ON tb_Apartamentos.cod_Apartamento = tb_DisponibilidadeApartamentos.cod_Apartamento
        )
        LEFT JOIN 
        tb_FotoApartamentos 
            ON tb_Apartamentos.cod_Apartamento = tb_FotoApartamentos.cod_Apartamento
    )
WHERE tb_Apartamentos.cod_Apartamento = 5;
```

Output returned by query:

```
Quarto e sala super aconchegante equipado com TV a cabo, internet wireless e ar condicionado. O destaque fica por conta da excelente localização: Rua Bolívar, entre os Postos 4 e 5. Está a poucos metros do Baixo Copacabana, encontro das ruas Domingo
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is only returning 255 characters or are you using MS Server Management Studio or something which is limiting the amount of data returned?  Query analyzer only shows 255 chars in a column unless you change it.

Comment: I'm working only into Access 2013 for a while. And if use 'SELECT tb_Apartamentos.txt_Descricao from tb_Apartamentos' it shows all characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this solution in another website http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/query-returns-first-255-characters-memo-field-t2603141.html:

```
The core if the issue is that Access returns only the first 255 characters
if it has to process the field.

That applies if you Group By a memo field (totals query), or if the query
deduplicates records (e.g. it has a DISTINCT or UNION), or if formatting is
applied to the field.

Examples of solving the problem:
a) If it is a Totals query, you could solve the problem by chosing First in
the Total row under the memo field instead of Group By.

b) Use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

c) Remove the DISTINCT. (If necessary, you can save the query without the
memo, and then build another query on top of that to get the memo.)

d) Remove anything from the Format property of the field in your table (or
the Format property of the text box on your form/report.)
```

I removed DISTINCT from my query and it works

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in tables and forms that were converted from 2010 to 2013. I noticed that an "@" was inserted into the format property of the Long Text fields/objects. Removing the "@" seemed to fix my problem so maybe your problem is the table rather than query.

Hope this helps.